# SailsJS production mode not responding on localhost:1337

Tags: sails.js

This might be a very newbie question, but I can't seem to get my Sails.js app working in production mode. I start it in production mode by setting NODE_ENV=production and it says it has lifted successfully on localhost:1337 but when I try to go to the link it just time out with no reply from server.

The Sails.js app works fine in development mode.

Been through all the documentation and can't see what am missing.

I have a production.js config file.

-- production.js (endpoints anonymized) ---

```
/**
 * Production environment settings
 *
 * This file can include shared settings for a production environment,
 * such as API keys or remote database passwords.  If you're using
 * a version control solution for your Sails app, this file will
 * be committed to your repository unless you add it to your .gitignore
 * file.  If your repository will be publicly viewable, don't add
 * any private information to this file!
 *
 */

module.exports = {

  minicabit: {
    api: {
      host: "https://api-endpoint",
      prepend: "/vX/",
      key: "wrwerwrwrwewre"
    }
  },
  log: {
    level: 'info'
  },
  csrf: true,

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the default database connection for models in the production        *
   * environment (see config/connections.js and config/models.js )           *
   ***************************************************************************/

  models: {
    connection: 'connMysql'
  },


  // models: {
  //   connection: 'someMysqlServer'
  // },

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the port in the production environment to 80                        *
   ***************************************************************************/

  //port: 80,

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the log level in production environment to "silent"                 *
   ***************************************************************************/

  // log: {
  //   level: "silent"
  // }

  blueprints: {
    rest: false,
    shortcuts: false
  },

  session: {

    /***************************************************************************
     *                                                                          *
     * In production, uncomment the following lines to set up a shared redis    *
     * session store that can be shared across multiple Sails.js servers        *
     ***************************************************************************/

    adapter: 'connect-redis',

    /***************************************************************************
     *                                                                          *
     * The following values are optional, if no options are set a redis         *
     * instance running on localhost is expected. Read more about options at:   *
     * https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis                             *
     *                                                                          *
     *                                                                          *
     ***************************************************************************/

    host: 'redis-endpoint',
    port: 6379,
    ttl: 3600
    // db: 0,
    // pass: <redis auth password>,
    // prefix: 'sess:'
  }
};
```

---

Am I missing anything else?

Thanks

Comment: There's not enough info here to make an educated guess.  Can you post the contents of your `production.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, it looks like the connect-redis module I installed is not compatible with sail.js

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2379